# How to find out the API group a resource belongs to?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

In my k3s cluster, I am editing a `Role` to add permission to a resource e.g. `deployment`.

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2023-09-02T08:00:23Z"
  name: foo
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "432595"
  uid: 603d0e0b-62f8-4e46-a42c-66436203bdc9
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - apps. # I know API Group is 'apps' but I wonder how to figure it out in general
  resources:
  - deployments
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
```

In the `apiGroups` field above, I know the API group for `deployment` resource is `app` based on my googling.

But I wonder in general how can I figure out which API group certain resource belongs to using `kubectl` command?

For example, I know also there is `kubectl api-resources` command, but if I run it for `deployment` resource as an example:

```
k api-resources | grep 'deployment'
NAME            SHORTNAMES   APIVERSION   NAMESPACED   KIND
deployments     deploy       apps/v1      true         Deployment
```

The output tells me the `APIVERSION` is `apps/v1`.  But what exactly is the **API Group** when I see value of `apps/v1`? Should I consider the value of `APIVERSION` is the API Group of this resource or is it always the left side of `/` be the API group?

Could someone please clarify for me? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can consider that the left side of the `/` is always the apiGroup. `app/v1` indicates the **REST API path**, in general the api path looks like `/apis/$GROUP\_NAME/$VERSION` where app is the [**apiGroup**](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/#api-groups) and **v1** is the **apiVersion.**

There is one exception though, if you are using components from **core group** or **legacy group**, the definition looks like `apiVersion: v1` instead of `apiVersion: core/v1`.

When we are trying to use a particular object, let's say `role` in your example, we can go through the official documentation of that particular component or you can also go through the **[api reference documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.28/)** for finding the **apiGroup** of that object.